# How to get addresses of the devices try to connect to mobile device via blue tooth

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile

Im very new to samsung ble(bluetooth low energy) SDK. The thing is I want to get addresses of several devices which try to connect to my mobile phone. please help me. thanks in advance.

Pradeep.

---

Thank you Akuzma,

This function gives all the paired devices. But I need to get the address of the device which is currently communicating with my mobile phone. for example if my phone is connected to 3 devices, but currently it will be communicating with only first device. So I need to get the address of that device, instead of getting all the addresses of connected devices.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use BluetoothAdapter

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
// If there are paired devices
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
    // Loop through paired devices
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
        mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Akuzma,

This function gives all the paired devices. But I need to get the address of the device which is currently communicating with my mobile phone. for example if my phone is connected to 3 devices, but currently it will be communicating with only first device. So I need to get the address of that device, instead of getting all the addresses of connected devices.

Thank you.